# How do I make an MFC control register for its own messages/events?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am working on a class derived from **CRichEditCtrl**. I want an instance of my class to know:

**Update**: solved it now.

1. <strike>when it has been Created (i.e the HWND is non-null)</strike>
2. <strike>when it gains/loses focus</strike>
3. <strike>when the text changes</strike>
4. <strike>when the selection changes</strike>
5. <strike>when a right-click has happened (I'm guessing through EN_MSGFILTER)</strike>

For 1, I found that overriding PreSubclassWindow works - the HWND is already associated with the CWnd by this point.

2,3,4 I figured out, partially. I can use `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(EN_CHANGE/EN_SETFOCUS/EN_KILLFOCUS)` & `ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(EN_SELCHANGE)`. *But* these only work if I call `SetEventMask(GetEventMask() |ENM_CHANGE | ENM_SELCHANGE | ENM_MOUSEEVENTS)` and you can't call that until the class has a HWND associated - doing it in the class construstor causes problems. And I can't see how to get 1. to work to solve this neatly.

<strike>I can see that `CRichEditCtrl` has two versions of `Create`:</strike>

```
BOOL Create(DWORD dwStyle, const RECT& rect, CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT nID);
BOOL CreateEx(DWORD dwExStyle, DWORD dwStyle, const RECT& rect,CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT nID);
```

So I added virtual versions of these to my class and put breakpoints on. Neither is ever called. Could that be due to missing out on MFC 'subclassing'/registration?

Answer (score 0):

CWnd::Create is a virtual function.  If you override it and call your base class's (CRichEditCtrl's) Create first, you can then assume the Window handle is available.

Something like this:

```
   BOOL MyEditControl::Create(
     LPCTSTR lpszClassName,
     LPCTSTR lpszWindowName,
     DWORD dwStyle,
     Const RECT& rect,
     CWnd* pParentWnd,
     UINT nID,
     CCreateContext* pContext)
   {
    CRichEditControl::Create(lpszClassName, lpszWindowName, dwStyle, rect, pParentWnd, nID, pContext);
    // call functions that use the window handle

   }
```

Comment: Tried that, see my edit. Doesn't work. But in my .rc file I have a standard **CRichEditCtrl**, bound to a **MyEditCtrl** using DDX. I guess that only works on methods declared virtual in **CRichEditCtrl**. What else do I need to add?

Comment: I'm a little confused.  If Create/CreateEx is never called, how could MyEditCtrl ever have a window handle?

Answer (score 0):

From your response to the earlier answer, it sounds a lot like you've got a CRichEditCtrl in a dialog. In MFC the dialog case is different from creating controls manually: the dialog controls (that is, the Windows controls, not the MFC objects) are created by the dialog manager, which are then coupled to the MFC objects by bits of the MFC infrastructure.

As you've found, in this case the MFC Create() or CreateEx() function is never called. Instead, the dialog manager creates the control, and it's attached to the MFC object by a call to SubclassDlgItem(). If you override that function, you'll find that it's called during dialog creation.

However, an easier way to deal with what you want is to put the call to SetEventMask() in the dialog's OnInitDialog() handler. This handler runs in response to the WM_INITDIALOG message, which is sent just after all the Windows controls are created and tied to the MFC objects.

Comment: This actually didn't work either. I updated my question with the solution I used.

Comment: OnInitDialog is the standard way to do this - it's what everyone does. Not sure why it didn't work for you, but it's worth trying to figure out why it didn't.